# Hibernate order of Operations clashes with UniqueConstraint

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb

The order in which Hibernate performs the delete/insert when updating a collection causes a unique constraint I want to define to fail. Hibernate tries to first insert new elements and then delete old ones. Inserting the new records causes my unique constraint to fail even though the database would be in a valid state after all operations have concluded.

**My entities**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Car")
public class Car {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "idCar")
   private long idCar;


   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "car", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<Wheel> wheels = new ArrayList<>();

// getters/setters ommitted
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Wheel", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"index", "idCar"})})
public class Wheel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "idWheel")
  private long idWheel;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "idCar")
  private Car car;

  @Column(name = "`index`")
  private int index;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

// getters/setters ommitted
}
```

**Example of Usage**

```java
    public void createCar() {
    Car car = new Car();

    List<Wheel> wheels = new ArrayList<>();
    wheels.add(new Wheel(car,1,"Continental"));
    wheels.add(new Wheel(car,2,"Continental"));
    wheels.add(new Wheel(car,3,"Continental"));
    wheels.add(new Wheel(car,4,"Continental"));

    car.setWheels(wheels);

    carRepository.save(car);


}

public void updateCar(long idCar) {

    Car car = carRepository.findById(idCar).get();

    List<Wheel> wheels = new ArrayList<>();
    wheels.add(new Wheel(car,1,"Pirelli"));
    wheels.add(new Wheel(car,2,"Pirelli"));
    wheels.add(new Wheel(car,3,"Pirelli"));
    wheels.add(new Wheel(car,4,"Pirelli"));

    car.setWheels(wheels);

    carRepository.save(car);
}
```

This behavior seems to be intended and there is no way to modify hibernate to execute the deletes first.
[This Bugreport was rejected](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2801)

My database (MariaDB) sadly does not support deferred unique constraints which seem like the optimal solution. I could remove the constraint or modify my application code to first manually delete any orphans and flush but both of these solutions seem suboptimal.

Are there any better workarounds I have missed? What is the best practice approach?

Answer (score 0):

When working with bidirectional association one has to keep the association in sync at all times ([this is in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional)).

You need to change your code to:

```
car.setWheels(wheels);
for (Wheel wheel : wheels) {
    wheel.setCar(car);
}
```

Or even better, you can create a utility method:

```
car.addWheel(wheel);
```

```
class Car {

   ...

   public void addWheel(Wheel wheel) {
       this.wheels.add(wheel);
       wheel.setCar(this);
   }

   ...
}
```